# Этимология выражения "шерочка-машерочка"

Tags: этимология

Собственно говоря, сабж интересует:

> Этимология выражения: *шерочка-машерочка*

В частности, часто употребляется в контексте: *ходят как шерочка с машерочкой* - в смысле постоянно вместе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В выражении: шерочка с машерочкой (разг. фам. шутл.) - о женщинах, танцующих вместе в одной паре за отсутствием кавалеров, как утверждает Ушаков.

От обычного обращения институток друг к другу по-французски ma chère (моя дорогая)- русское  шерочки (фр. chère - дорогая).

Comment: >фр. chйre - дорогая

Простите, но у вас опечатка или неудачное копирование

*Cher* или *chère*.

Comment: Копирование, конечно.Это у нас такие словари-онлайн,увидела, когда уже отправила, было некогда править, что-то виснет компьютер, так и оставила.

Comment: В разговорной речи присутствуют и другие такого рода словоформы: танечка-матанечка, такая-растакая, этакий-разэтакий, мало-помалу.